# joint probability of dice and coin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

I have a question where $X_1$ is the number on a die $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ and $X_2$ is the number of die plus the value of indicator on coin $(H=1, T=0)$. Find the joint probability of $X_1$ & $X_2$ , when die and coin tossed together. How will we find the joint distribution ? Thanks for positive response

Answer (score 3):

Only the value pairs $(n,n)$ and $(n,n+1)$, where $n=1,\ldots 6$ are possible, so 12 possible pairs.

Then $P(X_1 = n \land X_2 = n) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{12}$ because we have to throw $n$ with the die and tails with the coin, independently.

Similarly $P(X_1 = n \land X_2 = n+1) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{12}$ too. All $12$ possible outcome pairs are equiprobable, with fair coin and die.

Comment: sir there will be 42 possible joints as (6*7) ? is the joint will same for each 42 pairs ?? P(X1=3 & X2 = 3) ?? and P(X1=4 , X2=5) ?? and so on

Comment: @rizwanniaz there are $12$ options with non-zero probability; the rest has probability $0$, so $P(X_1=4, X_2 =2)=0$,but $P(X_1 =2, X_2=3) = \frac{1}{12}$, and $P(X_1=4, X_2=5) = \frac{1}{12}$ etc. So initially there seem to be 42 options, but only 12 are nonzero.

Comment: P(X1=4,X2=2)=0 why this is  zero i actually want to know reason and why P(X1=2,X2=3)=1\12 , im interested in this answer plz explain sir

Comment: @rizwanniaz If $X_1=4$ this mean we throw $4$ with the die. $X_2$ is $4$ plus $0,1$ depending on the coin toss. So $X_2$ cannot be $2$ or $3$ etc, just $4$ or $5$. The others are $\frac{1}{12}$ because every combination of die throw and coin toss is one of $12$ equiprobable options.

Comment: absolutely yes there are 12 options i made which have 1\12 and others have 0 probability because their sum are explosive ,......

Comment: P(sum is one | X1= 1) ?? from this question what will be the answer

Comment: @rizwanniaz $P(X_2=1|X_1=1) = P(T=0) = \frac12$.

Comment: sir is it 6 possibility of T= 0 , thats y u put 6\12 = 1\2 
i think now im cleared ????

Comment: thanks so much for giving ur time , stay blessed sir

Comment: @rizwanniaz $P(X_2=3| X_1=0)=P(\text{heads})= \frac12$ as well.

Comment: x1 shows the number on die , how it is zero ? as u put x1= 0

Comment: @rizwanniaz I meant $X_1=2$. Editing on a phone.

Comment: yes yes i understand very clearly thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ denote the number of the coin

In this situation most likely you are allowed to assume that $X_1$ and $C$ are **independent** random variables.

Moreover the random variables are discrete and then the joint PMF can be found as:$$P((X_1,C)=(x_1,c))=P(X_1=x_1,C=c)=P(X_1=x_1)P(C=c)$$where the second equality is a consequence of the independence.

Characteristic for independent random variables: if the marginal distributions are known then also the joint distribution can be found. This is not so if independence lacks.

---

Now observe that: $\{X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2\}=\{X_1=x_1,C=x_2-x_1\}$ so that $$P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)=P(X_1=x_1,C=x_2-x_1)=P(X_1=x_1)P(C=x_2-x_1)$$

I leave it up to you to find for what pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ this probability is positive.

Comment: sir if i add further information as P(sum =1 given that X1=1) now plz ,how can find joint ??

Comment: im yet not able to make joint after getting ur response even

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you find e.g. $P(X_1=5,C=1)$ on base of my answer? Can you find e.g. $P(X_1=5,X_2=6)$ on base of my answer? If so then your original question has been answered, hasn't it? If not then what lacks? Btw, I am leaving now. Later I will come back.

Comment: im interested to get answer in digit , i am not able to find probability of that P(X1=5,X2=6) Can u help me to find out that in this situation when a die and a coin toss together im confused in sample space and how to collect this event P(x1=5 & x2=6) from sample space

Comment: $P(X_1=5,X_2=6)=P(X_1=5,C=6-5=1)=P(X_1=5)P(C=1)=\frac16\frac12=\frac1{12}$. As sample space you can take $\{1,\dots,6\}\times\{0,1\}$ with equiprobable outcomes. Then $\{X_1=5,X_2=6\}=\{X_1=5,C=1\}=\{(5,1)\}$.

Comment: great sir ,thanks so much